# Does the following Flutter reading / writing files document have wasteful implementation?

Tags: dart, flutter

from the [flutter doc](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/):

```
class CounterStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<int> readCounter() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();

      return int.parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      // If we encounter an error, return 0
      return 0;
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$counter');
  }
}
```

Both `readCounter()` and `writeCounter()` call the `_localPath` getter each time they're called.

My question is :

isn't this a little wasteful? Wouldn't it be better to wait for the `_localFile` in the constructor of `CounterStorage`, and store it in a class member, as opposed to getting the `_localPath` and `_localPath` each and every time?

Can someone please suggest such an implementation?

Comment: You cant make a constructor async. The implementation could be a bit more efficient by saving the results of the `_local*` variable lookups the first time they are resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by wasteful, and the contract of `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory`.

For example, if it is possible for `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` to return a *different* path the next time it is called (for example, if a new user logs in, possibly - I'm not sure of the details) then this is completely correct.

If it is guaranteed this value will never change, it is *possible* to optimize further, but showing optimizations is probably not the goal of sample documentation. If you're interested, two ideas I can think of are:

### Create a `static final` field:

```
class CounterStorage {
  // Static fields in Dart are lazy; this won't get sent until used.
  static final _localPath = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((p) => p.path);

  // ...
}
```

This is my preference if `CounterStorage` has other methods or fields that are *uesful* without waiting for `_localPath` to be resolved. In the above example, there are none, so I would prefer:

### Create a `static` `async` method to create `CounterStorage`

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class CounterStorage {
  // You could even combine this with the above example, and make this a
  // static final field.
  static Future<CounterStorage> resolve() async {
    final localPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return new CounterStorage(new File(this.localPath));
  }

  final File _file;

  // In a test you might want to use a temporary directory instead.
  @visibleForTesting
  CounterStorage(this._file);

  Future<int> readCount() async {
    try {
      final contents = await _file.readAsString();
      return int.parse(contents);
    } catch (_) {
      return 0;
    }
  } 
}
```

This makes the process of retrieving the `File` happen potentially once per app.

Comment: when does _file actually get set in that example?